# trigger $scope function in controller from directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a directive that use keypup to prevent any null value, the min value is 1, like this

```
.directive('numberOfUsesMustNotNull', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'C',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            element.bind('keyup', function($event) {
                // disallow number of uses to be zero
                if(element.val() === '' || element.val() === 0){
                  element.val(1);
                }
            });
        }
    }
});
```

so I use it like

```
<input class="form-control numberOfUsesMustNotNull" type="number" placeholder="Qty" ng-model="qty" ng-change="updatePrice (qty)" />
```

in the view. but if the directive been triggered, the updatePrice function won't trigger. How do I trigger controller's $scope.updatePrice from directive?

Answer (score 0):

You can do a two-way binding for the variable.
Check two-way binding for directives in the Angular documentation here:
https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive

Do the following changes in your code:

```
<input class="form-control numberOfUsesMustNotNull" price="{{updatedPrice}}" ng-value="updatedPrice" type="number" placeholder="Qty" ng-model="qty" ng-change="updatePrice(qty)" />
```

And in the directive:

```
.directive('numberOfUsesMustNotNull', function() {
    return {
        scope: {
          price: "="
        },
        restrict: 'C',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            element.bind('keyup', function($event) {
                // disallow number of uses to be zero
                if(element.val() === '' || element.val() === 0){
                  scope.price = 1;
                }
            });
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: why u need ng-value for?

Answer (score 0):

> I have a directive that use keypup to prevent any null value, the min value is 1

**Why you need directive for that?**

using `min` attribute,you can achieve same things.

```
<input type="number" ng-model="qty" ng-change="updatePrice ()" min="1"/>
```

JS :

```
.controller('testCtrl',function($scope){
    $scope.updatePrice = function(){

        console.log($scope.qty);
    }
})
```

No need to pass `qty` from html.it is available on `$scope`.

Answer (score 0):

You should be using `ng-model` on the input field. Then your directive can use `require` to change the actual value that is bound to scope, as opposed to just the dom value. That will trigger ng-change properly.

Docs on ngModel: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModel
Docs on require: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive (under "directives that communicate" header)